# Why does TableAdapter not recognize parameters in OFFSET and FETCH clauses?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

I am using the VS 2015 TableAdapter Query Configuration Wizard, and want it to run a query with pagination:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo_dev.v_details 
WHERE (agent_name = @agentName) 
ORDER BY initiated_datetime DESC
OFFSET (@pageSize * (@pageNumber - 1)) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
```

It whines that it is "Unable to parse query text."

I did find [a previous posting referencing this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098048/why-tableadapter-doesnt-recognize-parameter) for VS 2012.  It states that the wizard can't recognize parameters outside of the SELECT and WHERE clauses.  Is this still the case, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that wizard has seen any substantial updates since, oh, Visual Studio 2005. Typed `DataSet`s and their associated wizards are very old. If the lackluster performance of `DataTable` didn't drive you to hand-written `SqlDataReader` code already, then LINQ to SQL, then LINQ to EF, then the rise of micro-ORM frameworks has mostly eaten the rest of their lunch. This isn't an answer to your question, more a recommendation not to sink too much time into the problem and avoid anything related to `DataTable` altogether.

Comment: The only thing you are doing wrong is working with this wizard... as Jeroen wrote, it's outdated.

Comment: Alright then, what is the most common current approach to running simple queries against the DB?  I've already given up and started using SqlDataReader at this point :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the previous post I mentioned, it appears that this is broken and not being fixed in VS.